# How can I include PyQt4 as one of the required installs for my python module while packaging it using setuptools?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, setuptools, distutils

I have an application that I want to make a package and share it. This app of mine uses `PyQt4` of version 4.10.3. Now, I add the following to the `install_requires` option in my `setup.py` file: ["pyqt4 >= 4.10.3", ]. However, I am not sure why, but it doesn't seem to be able to find PyQt4 on PyPi. What am I missing here? Could anyone help me out?

Comment: That question is slightly out of date, since PyQt4 is [actually on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyQt4/) nowadays… but it's still not installable via `pip`/`easy_install`/`install_requires`, so it's still the same problem.

Comment: @abarnert, Thanks. Actually, that was why I had posted the question again. In the accepted answer I see that we can "repackage PyQt with distutils". Any help on how that can be done?

Comment: I believe there used to be a page on Riverbank's site explaining that this is not a bug, it's intentional, for two reasons: (a) you'd still need to require people to manually install the Qt4 libs on most platforms, so you might as well, and (b) it could lead your users to violate the PyQt license without realizing it.

Comment: I think the answered was suggesting that the OP could do all the work himself to create a `pip`-able `setup.py` for PyQt4… Anyway, you can package PyQt4 into a binary app install with most tools (py2exe, py2app, cx_Freeze, etc.), and of course if you're building a deb/rpm/port/recipe/etc. you can add it as a dependency at that level… but for source installs you basically need to tell people to install both Qt4 and PyQt4.